# Import data from GitHub

Tags: r, github, data-import

I'm trying to import this data set from GitHub:

https://github.com/shifteight/R/blob/master/TRB/data/worldfloras.txt

I tried it the following way:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url<-"https://github.com/shifteight/R/blob/master/TRB/data/worldfloras.txt"
urldata<-getURL(url)
data<-readHTMLTable(url data, header=TRUE, sep="\t" stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Though I use sep=”\t", my output is the following.

```
    $`NULL`
 Country\tLatitude\tArea\tPopulation\tFlora\tEndemism\tContinent
    1                       Afghanistan\t30\t636\t14.3\t3000\t0.27\tAsia
    2                            Albania\t42\t29\t3\t3200\t0.008\tEurope
    3                      Algeria\t35\t2382\t21.3\t3139\t0.08\tN.Africa
```

...

Does anyone have an explanation for that? I'd be very happy if someone finds a solution to my problem.

Comment: Use the raw link `read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shifteight/R/master/TRB/data/worldfloras.txt", header = TRUE)`

Comment: @zx8754 wow.  You beat me to that by about 5 seconds.

Comment: Another version of the "raw"-link: https://github.com/shifteight/R/raw/master/TRB/data/worldfloras.txt

Comment: Thank you very much. However, it still does not work, as there are more columns than column names. Is there anything I can do to circumvent this problem?

Comment: With the second link it now works. Thank you very much indeed! :)